# Linux: bash: Can't ls a file in a directory containing single quote

Tags: linux, bash, quoting

This ought to be simple.  I have a bash script which reads simply:

ls "$1"

This fails if $1 happens to contain a single quote.  For example, if the input is:

"/home/test/temp's/testing.txt"

I get:

ls: cannot access '"/home/test/temp'''s/testing.txt"': No such file or directory

This problem occurs with cd and many other commands.
OK, I can double-quote the argument, but I may not have the choice, if the filename is generated by another program.  Any ideas?

Comment: `but I may not have the choice, if the filename is generated by another program` ? What do you mean but "not have a choice"? just `cd "$(a_program_that_generates_the_filename)"`. `This fails if $1 happens to contain a single quote` - [works for me](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/PlainTangibleWorker#main.sh). Probably there really is no such file or directory.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you have a typo in your file name?

Comment: My particular instance is when the file is supplied by nemo actions in response to a right-click menu option (%F in the "Exec=" clause).

Answer (score 0):

You can escape a single quote with backslash `\`

Suppose you have an empty script.sh with just a one line line `ls "$1"`
and a file `my'file.txt`, then if you call it:

```
$ script.sh my\'file.txt
```

outputs with  no errors:

```
"my'file.txt"
```

the same applies to directories:

```
$ ls my\'dir
```

Comment: The Problem is that I have a file in ~/.local/share/nemo/actions, which is as follows:

[Nemo Action]
Name=List\n
Comment=Special directory listing
Exec=\""/home/test/lister.sh"\" %F
Icon-Name=
Selection=all
Quote=double
Extensions=txt;
Terminal=true

If I right click on a filename and select "List", the script calls the nemo action, passing the path name as %F.
However, if the path contains a single quote, the script fails as described above.